# Web-App for to determine gender, age, emotions of a person (shown on an image)

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, promise, azure

I have made an app using Microsoft's Face API: [Face API JavaScript Quick Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/javascript)

It shall analyze an image, showing a person's portrait, concerning the gender of the person, her/his age and emotions.

One pastes the URL of an image into the text-box. Then clicks the button.

The results are then listed below the image.

**Caution! I'm using a free, temporary key in there. The app might stop working some time after my post.**

```js
(function(window) {
  var headersObject = new Headers();
  var photo = document.getElementById('analyzedPhoto');
  var attributesList = document.getElementById('attributes');

  headersObject.append('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', '32fee7696d9545bdab41fd09ffb00034');
  headersObject.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  document
    .getElementById('analyse')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {
      var imgUrl = document.getElementById('imageUrl').value;

      var initObject = {
        headers: headersObject,
        method: 'post',
        body: '{"url": "' + imgUrl + '"}'
      }

      photo.src = imgUrl;

      fetch('https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceAttributes=emotion,age,gender', initObject)
        .then((response) => {
          !response.ok &&
            Promise.reject(new Error('The request of analysis data has failed.'));

          return response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
          let facesAttributes =
            Object.assign({},
              json[0].faceAttributes,
              json[0].faceAttributes.emotion);
          let listItems = [];
          // Otherwise emotion-properties AND emotion-object self are contained in attributes-object.
          delete facesAttributes.emotion;

          for (let key in facesAttributes) {
            listItems.push('<li class="list-item"><span class="list-item-key">' +
              (key.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()) +
              (key.slice(1)) + '</span>: ' + facesAttributes[key] +
              '</li>');
          }

          attributesList.innerHTML = listItems.join('');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.dir(error);
          attributesList.innerHTML = 'Have you entered a valid image URL?';
        });
    });
})(window);
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.main-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#imageUrl {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 780px;
}

#analyzedPhoto {
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#attributes {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#attributes .list-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list-item-key {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <h1>Enter Image URL</h1>

  <section>
    <p>
      <input type="text" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Tesla3.jpg/220px-Tesla3.jpg" id="imageUrl" />
    </p>
    <button id="analyse">Analyse</button>
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" id="analyzedPhoto" alt="Photo to analyze" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Attributes</h2>
    <ul id="attributes"></ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Is my usage of the fetch-API and Promises correct and done in a good way?**

These concepts are fairly new to me.

Moreover: I had a bit of hassle merging the two objects into one. Please see my comment within the code.

**Is there a better solution than deleting the unnecessary sub-object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Addressing Your Questions

> Is my usage of fetch-API and Promises correct and done in a good way?

Yes it seems fine. The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is supported by all major browsers but not IE<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Browser_compatibility)</sup> but some [argue that it doesn't really have a simple way to cancel requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178156/comment-list-using-reactjs/178158#comment338287_178158). If there arises a need to abort requests, then other libraries like [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or reqwest could be used.

> Is there are better solution then deleting the unnecessary sub-object?

Obviously there are other ways to handle setting the values within the *emotion* property on `faceAttributes`, but those might likely require more lines. One could also conditionally display list items (e.g. add `if (typeof facesAttributes[key] !== "object") {` before the line that pushes strings into `listItems`). If there was a way to filter with a callback when calling `Object.extend()` that would be an advantage here but unfortunately it doesn't appear that is the case.

## Other review points

### Feedback

The code looks quite succint. There are two DOM lookups at the start but then one DOM lookup in the click handler so that could be cached in a variable.

### Suggestions

#### `var` vs `let`/`const`

Perhaps you have already learned more about `let` and `const` since posting this question but many es-6 developers would prefer using `const` for values that don't change (e.g. `imgUrl`, `initObject`, etc.)

#### Template

One could also utilize a [script template](https://www.codereadability.com/constructing-html-with-templates/#movingthehtmloutofthejavascriptfile) to display the list items, though that may not be desirable here.

#### Invalid HTML when Error occurs

This line in the promise catch:

> ```
> attributesList.innerHTML = 'Have you entered a valid image URL?';
> ```

Sets the inner HTML of the unordered list tag to a text string. That is technically unpermitted content for [an unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). Perhaps a better solution would be to have a separate element for the error message.

#### P.S.

Here is the output from that AJAX call using [that image of Tesla](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Tesla3.jpg/220px-Tesla3.jpg), so you could fake it now that the key is invalid:

```js
const output = [{"faceId":"950c26ae-70f0-4365-8279-fcd987f56e70","faceRectangle":{"top":75,"left":32,"width":117,"height":117},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"male","age":37.0,"emotion":{"anger":0.0,"contempt":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":0.007,"neutral":0.992,"sadness":0.0,"surprise":0.0}}}];
const p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, output);
  });
p1.then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Other side of the coin

> Is there are better solution then deleting the unnecessary sub-object?

After thinking about this a little more, I feel like one could utilize [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with a recrusive assignment function and more es-6 features like [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to avoid the `delete` operation:

```
const facesAttributes = {};
const handleEntries = ([key, value]) => typeof value === "object" ? Object.entries(value).forEach(handleEntries) : facesAttributes[key] = value;
Object.entries(json[0]).forEach(handleEntries);
```

So while it may not be any shorter, there is no need to use the `delete` operation. I tried using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) but wasn't able to find a way to have a one-line arrow function that both assigned values to the accumulator object and returned the accumulator object.

#### `const` instead of `let`

I know it has already been mentioned that `const` can be used instead of `var` for some values that don't change (e.g. `imgUrl`, `initObject`, etc.). There are also some block-scoped variables declared using `let` that can be declared using `const` since they are never re-assigned: `facesAttributes` and `listItems`.

#### Updated code

```js
(function(window) {
  var headersObject = new Headers();
  var photo = document.getElementById('analyzedPhoto');
  var attributesList = document.getElementById('attributes');

  headersObject.append('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', '32fee7696d9545bdab41fd09ffb00034');
  headersObject.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  document
    .getElementById('analyse')
    .addEventListener('click', () => {
      const imgUrl = document.getElementById('imageUrl').value;

      const initObject = {
        headers: headersObject,
        method: 'post',
        body: '{"url": "' + imgUrl + '"}'
      }

      photo.src = imgUrl;

      const output = [{"faceId":"950c26ae-70f0-4365-8279-fcd987f56e70","faceRectangle":{"top":75,"left":32,"width":117,"height":117},"faceAttributes":{"gender":"male","age":37.0,"emotion":{"anger":0.0,"contempt":0.0,"disgust":0.0,"fear":0.0,"happiness":0.007,"neutral":0.992,"sadness":0.0,"surprise":0.0}}}];
const p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, output);
  });
        p1.then((json) => {
        
          const facesAttributes = {};
          const handleEntries = ([key, value]) => typeof value === "object" ? Object.entries(value).forEach(handleEntries) : facesAttributes[key] = value;
          Object.entries(json[0]).forEach(handleEntries);
      
          const listItems = [];

          for (let key in facesAttributes) {
            listItems.push('<li class="list-item"><span class="list-item-key">' +
              (key.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()) +
              (key.slice(1)) + '</span>: ' + facesAttributes[key] +
              '</li>');
          }

          attributesList.innerHTML = listItems.join('');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.dir(error);
          attributesList.innerHTML = 'Have you entered a valid image URL?';
        });
    });
})(window);
```

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.main-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#imageUrl {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 780px;
}

#analyzedPhoto {
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#attributes {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#attributes .list-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list-item-key {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <h1>Enter Image URL</h1>

  <section>
    <p>
      <input type="text" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Tesla3.jpg/220px-Tesla3.jpg" id="imageUrl" />
    </p>
    <button id="analyse">Analyse</button>
  </section>

  <section>
    <img src="" id="analyzedPhoto" alt="Photo to analyze" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Attributes</h2>
    <ul id="attributes"></ul>
  </section>
</div>
```