# Comment List using ReactJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, react.js, jsx

Looking for some ideas as to how to improve the below react component.

```
var JSON_URL = "https://api.example.io/comments.json";
class CommentList extends React.Component {  
    constructor() {    
        super();    
        this.state = { comments: [] }  
    }  
    componentDidMount() {    
        $.ajax({      
            url: JSON_URL,      
            dataType: 'json',      
            success: function(data) {        
                this.setState({comments: data.comments});      
            }.bind(this)    
        });  
    };  
    render() {    
        return <ul> {
            this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
                return <li>{comment.body}—{comment.author}</li>;                    
            })}
       </ul>;  
    }
}
React.render(<CommentList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ES6 arrow function

Nice work utilizing functional programming (i.e. `.map()`) and the arrow function. One improvement here is that there isn't much of a need for a code block (i.e. `{ ....}`) and `return` statement. So the callback to `.map()` in the `render` method can be reduced to a single line like below:

```
render() {    
    return <ul> {
        this.state.comments.map((comment) => <li>{comment.body}—{comment.author}</li>)
    }</ul>;  
}
```

#### jQuery - just for AJAX requests?

It appears that the only jQuery functionality used is its AJAX wrapper (i.e. `$.ajax()`). If that is all jQuery is used for, consider using a different technique like [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (read [this article](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/) for more info).

```
componentDidMount() {  
    fetch(JSON_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({comments: data.comments}));
```

See [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/QPlWoKF4SzmV8LvTsQKD/) for a demonstration.

### Update

It has been mentioned that [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) has no support for aborting the request. If that is desired, there are other alternatives like [Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) (recommended by [you might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ajax)). See [this updated plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9nmSX9loFr5dxRVNxZlD/) for an example of using superagent with its abort method in the *componentWillUnmount* method.

Comment: Unfortunately fetch doesn't support aborting ajax requests. In the case of this component, it makes sense to abort the request during `componentWillUnmount` if it didn't finish.

Comment: apparently there are new developments... see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785332/1575353)... sure I see that it is only supported in FF but hopefully others soon...